# React-Redux Transform data to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm implementing a Task App where I have two views to render `Tasks` and `Items` and one where I render multiple lists based on the Task Status as kanban board.

My reducer:

```
export const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
        Tasks: TasksReducer,
        itemsAreLoading: itemsAreLoadingReducer
    });

 const TasksReducer = (state , action )  => {

        if (typeof state == "undefined") {
            console.log('state undefined');
            return null;
        }

        switch (action.type) {

            case TasksTypes.Tasks_GET: 
                return action.Tasks;
            default:
                console.log(state);
                return state;
        }
    }

    export class TasksApp extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {

            const {tasks} = this.props;
            return (<div>
                    <ItemsView Tasks={tasks}/>
                    <BoardView Lanes=[/* tasks tranfromed into mutliple list based on their status*/]/>
                </div>);
        }

    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            tasks: state.Tasks 
        };
    };
```

My Question is where to transform the data for the second view to have a different representation of the data.

Comment: There is a slight error: `const tasks = this.props;` should be `const { tasks } = this.props;`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that you dont fire any actions in your class, and I dont see any actions here neither. So first, you have to fire an action, and dispatch it with the type and payload, second, as David Tyron wrote, the syntax was a bit off in this line:

```
const { tasks } = this.props;
```

And for the end a small remark, you can do some destruction in the mapStateToProps function:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ Tasks }) => {
        return { Tasks };
    };
```

And then get it like `const { Tasks } = this.props;`

I think, that the best practice to change your tasks props is to fire another action that creates a new props from your tasks props, something like:

```
    export const transformData = tasks => {
    return dispatch => {
    //Do the transformations here
    dispatch {
         type: TRANSFORM_DATA,
         payload: transformed_tasks
            } 
        }
    }
```

And then catch it with a reducer.

And IMHO, the best place to call this action is the `componentDidMount()`